# How to make a function to find 0

Tags: javascript

I have an arrays like:

```
["oh", 2]
["yes", 2]
["sheet", 2]
["really", 1]
["bro", 1]
["om", 0]
["a", 0]
["to", 0]
```

i needed to make checkout like second meaning of array doesn't be a 0, i try with function like *if arr != 0 return arr*, but it also return an undefined when find a value 0.
How can a make the output like word - number without arrays with 0 value?

For the example i need to output: oh - 2, yes - 2, sheet - 2, really - 1, bro - 1

Comment: Are those arrays contained within a larger Array? What have you attempted to solve your own problem, can you share that (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code? What went wrong with it, and in what way, were there any errors reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What about,**

```js
var arr = [
    ["oh", 2],
    ["yes", 2],
    ["sheet", 2],
    ["really", 1],
    ["bro", 1],
    ["om", 0],
    ["a", 0],
    ["to", 0]
];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i][1] == '0'){
        delete arr[i];
    }
}
arr = arr.filter(item => item);

//check
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: and also i need to check it, if an arr is [] it should output like: 'All is good' else it should save in two varibles the word and the number